# trying to use jsoup to login

Tags: authentication, jsoup

I am fairly new to Jsoup and trying to achieve / simulate login to a webpage

[Login url](https://www.example.com/member/public/login.emvc)

I am using the following code:

```
String url = "https://www.example.com/member/public/login.emvc";
Connection.Response res = Jsoup
    .connect(url)
    .data("j_username", "username")
    .data("j_password", "password")
    .data("submit", "Log In")
    .method(Method.POST)
    .execute();
System.out.println(res.url());
```

res.url prints as [same url as above](https://www.example.com/member/public/login.emvc)

It seems like they are using spring security. What am I missing?

Comment: Try this url https://www.eyemedvisioncare.com/member/secure/j_spring_security_login.emvc

Comment: @alkis thank you. that seems to have worked. I thought, I tried that earlier.

Comment: You can provide your own answer in the answer box provided and then accept it. This is preferable to editing the word "SOLVED" into the question.